# Delay after switching between x and -x axes

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm making a game similar to pong, where you have to move that white rectangle to destroy the black dots. However, if you go ahead and hold left arrow key then pressed the right arrow key there is a delay before the rectangle starts moving to the right side. I think it has to do with the moveSelection function.

```
<html>
<body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>    
<!--issue starts here-->

<script type="text/javascript">
            function leftArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("rec");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
            }

            function rightArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("rec");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

            }

            function moveSelection(evt) {
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                    leftArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 39:
                    rightArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 38:
                    upArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    case 40:
                    downArrowPressed();
                    break;
                    }
                };

        function docReady()
        {

          window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
        }
</script>

<!--issue ends here-->

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// newly spawned objects start at Y=0
var spawnLineY = 0;

// spawn a new object every 375ms
var spawnRate = 375;

// set how fast the objects will fall
var spawnRateOfDescent = 2.0;

// when was the last object spawned
var lastSpawn = 1.34;

// this array holds all spawned object
var objects = [];

// save the starting time (used to calc elapsed time)
var startTime = Date.now();

animate();


function spawnRandomObject() {

    // select a random type for this new object
    var t;

    // create the new object
    var object = {
        // set this objects type
        type: t,
        // set x randomly but at least 10px off the canvas edges
        x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 10,
        // set y to start on the line where objects are spawned
        y: spawnLineY,
    }

    // add the new object to the objects[] array
    objects.push(object);
}

function animate() {

    // get the elapsed time
    var time = Date.now();

    // see if its time to spawn a new object
    if (time > (lastSpawn + spawnRate)) {
        lastSpawn = time;
        spawnRandomObject();
    }

    // request another animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // clear the canvas so all objects can be 
    // redrawn in new positions
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // x is drawn randomly
    // y; draw the line where new objects are spawned
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, spawnLineY);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, spawnLineY);
    ctx.stroke();


    // move each object down the canvas
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var object = objects[i];
        object.y += spawnRateOfDescent;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
        ctx.fill();
    }

}

</script>

<style>

#rec {

    position: absolute;
}

#canvas {

    border: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: cadetblue;
    background: rgb(1,0,90);
    background: linear-gradient(75deg, rgb(85, 0, 0)3%, rgb(161, 0, 0) 50%, rgb(85, 0, 0) 100%);

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto

}

body {

background:rgb(23, 10, 206);
background:linear-gradient(75deg, rgb(9, 7, 116) 0%, rgb(23, 10, 206) 50%, rgb(9, 7, 116) 100%);

}

</style>
<img id="rec" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/580178253185155073/645595326769659934/Untitled-1.png" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0;" height="20" width="150">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what the problem you are facing can you specify it,provide some more description about it

Comment: I did if you run the code, press hold right arrow key then hold left arrow key the rectangle will take a few seconds before moving to the left.

Comment: i am not facing the problem described but if you want to ignore continuous pressing of arrow and only want to execute first one key press you should search about debouncing of key press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your code again,
the delay is because your element.style.left assigned with negative value when reached to zero and same will happen with right when reached to screen.width.
you need to stop it by checking the left value after assigning the new value in you left and right arrow press function like

```
function leftArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("rec");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
        //when you reach to zero
        if (parseInt(element.style.left) <= 0) {
            element.style.left = '0px';
        }
    }

    function rightArrowPressed() {
        var element = document.getElementById("rec");
        element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
        // when you reach to right border of the screen 
        if (parseInt(element.style.left) > window.screen.width - parseInt(element.width)) {
            element.style.left = window.screen.width - parseInt(element.width) + "px";
        }
    }
```

its worked for me ,check it